# Repeating attributes within primary key

Tags: sql

I have a primary key field it has repeating attributes whenever I remove these, the foreign key that I have for this table now has more rows. Each of the rows on the foreign key are unique. Do I remove the repeating attributes?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Please show some data to illustrate what you are saying.

Comment: [ask] and [mcve]